# Using Landing Page URL in Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, email-studio

I have created an email in which I have used a button in which I am passing the Cloud Page (Landing Page) URL. Does this makes this email a super message?[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no correlation between an email and a button leading to the CloudPage inside of the email from the perspective of supermessage consumption.
Here is an explanation of email supermessage consumption:

> Email Usage: an email message sent to a subscriber. Examples of email usage include normal email sends, normal email sends CC, normal email sends BCC, triggered send, triggered send CC, and triggered send BCC. For example, if you send an email to 100 subscribers and BCC 2 more emails, the total usage is 300 Emails: 100 normal email sends and 200 normal email sends BCC.

and CloudPage impression that consumes supermessages:

> CloudPages Impression: a successful request for a published CloudPage (200 OK). Examples of CloudPage impressions include landing pages, Microsites, MobilePush pages, and Interactive Email pages. Currently, Code Resources are not considered or counted as CloudPages impressions.

Sources to review:

- [Supermessage consumtion multipliers per type](https://www.salesforce.com/products/marketing-cloud/sfmc/sms-ratio-updates/)
- [Marketing Cloud data usage types](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_data_usage.htm&type=5)